# Chi-square test on contingency table (4x2) in R

Tags: r, chi-squared, contingency

I'm having trouble computing a chi-square test on my 4x2 contingency table in R. My script looks like following:

```
# Read data
read.table("Mortality_test.txt")

# Assign a name to the data
mortality<- read.table("Mortality_test.txt", ,col.names=c('treatment','dead'), header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="NA", dec=",", strip.white=TRUE)

table(mortality)
```

When i run the `table(mortality)` i get a contingency table that looks like following:

```
    dead
treatment no yes
     A    63   7
     B    61   9
     C    68   2
     D    63   7
```

My problem now is that I would like to compare if there's any statistical difference in deaths between the different treatments (A,B,C,D). If I'm not mistaken I'm able to do this with a chi-square test on the table. However, I'm not sure which step to take next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function `chisq.test` to perform the chi test on a contigency table.

Here, with your table

```
dead <- read.table(text = "treatment no yes
                   A    63   7
                   B    61   9
                   C    68   2
                   D    63   7",header = T)

> dead
  treatment no yes
1         A 40  15
2         B 61   9
3         C 68   2
4         D 63   7
```

You need to take the two columns no and yes:

```
chisq.test(dead[,2:3])


        Pearson's Chi-squared test

    data:  dead[, 2:3]
    X-squared = 4.6996, df = 3, p-value = 0.1952
```

Which doesn't give a difference between treatments. To see an other example with difference:

```
dead <- read.table(text = "treatment no yes
                   A    55   12
                   B    61   9
                   C    68   2
                   D    63   7",header = T)
```

where the A treatment is really different:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  dead[, 2:3]
X-squared = 8.4334, df = 3, p-value = 0.03785
```

Comment: Well that was pretty straight forward. Thanks a bunch for your quick answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

We can get the chi squared test conveniently by simply applying `summary()` on a `table()`.

#### Example

```
with(mtcars, table(cyl, gear))
#    gear
# cyl  3  4  5
#   4  1  8  2
#   6  2  4  1

summary(with(mtcars, table(cyl, gear)))
# Number of cases in table: 32 
# Number of factors: 2 
# Test for independence of all factors:
#         Chisq = 18.036, df = 4, p-value = 0.001214
#         Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

*Note:* The "Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect" is due to the fact that there are only 32 observations in this example.

With your data `summary(table(mortality))` should work.